# Sum up 126 previous values for variance forecast in a new column with fix range

Tags: python, sum, range, variance, forecast

I want to use a formula to make a variance forecast. I imported a CSV file in python with two columns : DATE and RETURN. Now I want to forecast the variance with the last 126 Return values. Therefore I want to add a new column to my data  starting from row 126, where the last 126 values for return are summed up and row 127 then I sum up the return values from row 2 to 127 and so on. Just like in Excel when I pull down my code for the next rows and my rows are now fixed, so the range moves downwards.

In total my Data has 24250 values, and I want to add a new row called SUM126

CODE:

```
#import file and skip first 14 rows because they are header
DATA = pd.read_csv('DATA.CSV',skiprows=14)
#Named the headers
header_names=['DATE','RETURN WML']
DATA = pd.read_csv('Thesis_DATA.CSV',skiprows=14,names = header_names)
#get the decimal in new column
DATA['(RETURN/100)'] = (DATA['RETURN WML']/100)
```

and now I want to add the new column, therefore I tried something like that:

```
#starting the new column in row 126,running over 1 steps till 24250
for i=(126:1:24250)
#I always want the sum of the last 126 values
    relevant_data= data(i-125:i);
#I am creating a new column 
    DATA['VARIANCE FORECAST']=(sum(relevant_data))
```

I am happy for any help!

Comment: If you show what you've tried so far, and indicate exactly where the roadblock is,  Stack Overflow can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show a Minimal, Verifiable, Working example for your problem.